# How to show the products group by different vendors in Odoo 8 "Invoice Line"?

Tags: odoo-8, odoo

I am using Odoo 8. "Sales > Confirmed Sales Order" in any invoiced sales order, the "Invoice Line" contains different vendor product. How can I separate different vendor products in one "Invoice Line". I want to show the products group by different vendors.

Any code or help link will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want different vendor product is invoice line. Like group by ?

Comment: yes. is this possible? programmatically in the view?

Comment: Just add a filed and manage via that.

Comment: can you please explain? I am new in Odoo? I do not know how to do.